# Git shows that a folder deleted, but git checkout <folder_name> can't bring it back?

Tags: git

If `git status` shows:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    FooBar.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

Isn't `git checkout` supposed to bring it back?

```
$ git checkout FooBar.xcodeproj
error: pathspec 'FooBar.xcodeproj' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

How can git correctly restore this folder?

Comment: Try what it asks you to `(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)`

Comment: The file name in question is `FooBar.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`, not just `FooBar.xcodeproj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FooBar.xcodeproj` is obviously a directory and not directly under version control. What you might try doing is forcing it to checkout the file again:

```
git checkout --  FooBar.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking svn here. That's not how git works. You don't checkout sub-directories.

If you want to reset the particular file to the HEAD, you reset it, like:

```
 git reset HEAD filename
```